# Desktop won't power on

Tags: power-supply, desktop-computer

I have a desktop, which suddenly couldn't be powered on. It just starts for a second and then turns off. If I keep pushing the `power` button the computer starts normally.

At first I thought that the problem was the ATX so I dismantled it, to check if everything works fine. I shorted the green wire to the ground and the ATX switched on.
I checked every voltage in all cables and everything seems to be working fine.

It cannot also be an overheating problem because the tower's interior is clean.

The last thing I noticed is that when the PSU is powered on by the switch, I can hear a couple of tick-tacks, before it is powered off.

Any idea on what might be the problem?

Comment: So as long as you **hold** the power button it turns on normally?

Comment: Η ΔΕΗ φταίει... Seriously though, do the fans start spinning when the PC is turned on?

Comment: @AthomSfere: It turns on just for a few seconds. But while it's on on you can hear something clicking, which isn't the HDD because I have it unplugged.

Comment: @terdon: Αχ αυτή η ΔΕΗ! The fans start spinning without any problem. When I say fans I mean all of the fans(PSU's, graphics card's and motherboard's).

Comment: @AthomSfere is asking if the computer will stay on _while_ you press the power button or if it will turn on normally after pressing the button a few times. The classic troubleshooting procedure here is to remove every component you can (including RAM and all cards) and try again.

Comment: @terdon: There are two scenarios: Either I press the power button instantly, it just turns on for one second or I keep it pressed. If I keep it pressed, the PC will turn on for 3-5 second, after it will turn itself off. During those 3-5 seconds I can hear a ticking noise from the PSU. The next step is to remove all cards and try again. But I cannot understand where the clicking noise comes from. What could be clicking inside the PSU?

Comment: @Thanos maybe something as pedestrian as a loose cable?

Comment: @terdon: I really doubt because I checked every cable. But I will check it again just in case.

Comment: The way the green wire short test worked, and various power button actions have different outcomes, I suspect the switch in the case...

Comment: @AthomSfere: I suspect the same. How tro check that? For now I equip the PSU into another desktop to see if it works.

Comment: Your green wire short essentially was a power switch test. It confirmed the hardware worked with a different "switch", or paper clip or whatever you used. So another case or switch in the old case is the only way to know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Check all molex plugs: disconnect them and connect again, one by one. Especially the large 20-pin (or 24-pin) plug. Check if everything is back to normal.

If it won't help, inspect the motherboard capacitors, especially ones located near the power section (usually located around CPU). Those tend to fail after some time (like 5 or 6 years, possibly faster if you have a cheap PSU). You'll identify bad capacitors by bulging, usually connected with small amounts of electrolyte on top. ([some photos here](http://www.capacitorlab.com/visible-failures/))

If you can see any suspicious-looking capacitors, those are probably the cause of the problem. Capacitor replacement is possible, although it requires some manual skills and makes your motherboard more prone to future failures (manual solders are never as solid as machine-made ones). Motherboard replacement is probably your best option.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The thing is that I have already inspected all caps, inside the tower as well as in the PSU. They are all OK. I have also done the plug check, but the behaviour remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you are seeing various degrees of success by playing with the switch, and also that shorting the green lead to ground caused everything to fire up and work properly says it is likely the switch on the case that is bad.

All you can really do is swap either the switch (Not easy in most computer cases) or swap cases.

Comment: You should be able to short the pins on the motherboard to check if its the case switch

Comment: @JourneymanGeek It sounds like he did that on the PSU, while it was connected...

Comment: yup, that would check if the PSU powers up, tho he needs to load it for a proper result. You can also short out the pins on the motherboard to check if its the case switch.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Unless I am missing something here: As long as the ATX 24 pin (presumably) is connected to the motherboard when you short the PSU then you still have load. The only difference is testing the actual front panel leads (Which I have never seen go bad personally...)

Comment: @AthomSfere: Thank you very much for your answer. Actually I haven't thought of plugging normally the PSU, without plugging the switch's plugs... You are saying to plug the PSU without the switch and just to short the motherboard's pins... I have also checked the PSU with another computer and it works fine. So double checked it's not the PSU!